# Oracle Linux 8.3 can't find libyaml-devel

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, package-management, oracle-linux

I'm evaluating Oracle Linux as a CentOS alternatives. During my tests I have to compile a package depending on `libyaml-devel` but the lib isn't present in the repo.

I had the impression Oracle Linux would provide the same packages as RHEL.
So why I can find it for RHEL but not Oracle? Do I miss something?

The [RHEL 8 packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/package_manifest/index) and the [Oracle one's](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/index.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable "PowerTools" repository equivalent. For Oracle Linux 8:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled ol8_codeready_builder
```

Comment: Great thanks, it show up using `dnf search libyaml-devel`.
I haven't came across it. Can you point me to the documentation please?

Comment: I couldn't locate any docs in Oracle about the repository. Used pkgs.org to see what is the repository containing `libyaml-devel`; following that, a google search on enabling PowerTools repo in Oracle Linux 8 will bring you [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4314646/powertools-and-pgadmin-4-on-oracle-linux-8) with someone stating the correct repository ID.